# Pushdown automata to accept the following language

Tags: formal-languages, pushdown-automaton

I need to construct a pushdown automation for the following language: L = {a^n b^m | 2n>=m }
Can someone help me with it?

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where are you stuck with your implementation? If you're unsure where to start, think about the language `L = { a^n b^m | n = m }`, then think about `L = { a^n b^m | n >= m }`. How would modify a PDA that accepts the first into one that accepts the second? Then, how about changing the constraint to `2n >= m`? If that doesn't help, please be more specific about what you need help with.

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches that come to mind:

1. try to write a PDA from scratch using the stack in a sensible way
2. write a CFG and then rely on the construction that shows PDAs accept the languages of all CFGs

To take approach 1, recognize that PDAs are like NFAs that can push symbols onto a stack and pop them off. If we want 2n >= m, that means we want the number of a's to be at least half the number of b's. That is, we want at least one a for every two b's. That means if we push all the a's on the stack, we need to read no more than two b's for every a on the stack. This suggests a PDA that works like this:

```
1. read all the a's, pushing into the stack
2. read b's, popping an a for every two b's you see
3. if you run out of stack but still have b's to process, reject
4. if you run out of input at the same time or sooner than you run out of stack, accept
```

In terms of states and transitions:

```
Q    S    E    Q'    S'

q0   Z    a    q0    aZ   // these transitions read all the a's and 
q0   a    a    q0    aa   // push them onto the stack

q0   a    b    q1    a    // these transitions read all the b's and
q1   a    b    q2    -    // pop a's off the stack for every complete
q2   a    b    q1    a    // pair of b's we see. if we run out of a's
                          // it will crash and reject

q0   Z    -    q3    Z    // these transitions just let us guess at any
q0   a    -    q3    a    // point that we have read all the input and
q1   Z    -    q3    Z    // go to the accepting state. note that if
q1   a    -    q3    a    // we guessed wrong the PDA will crash there
q2   Z    -    q3    Z    // since we have no transitions defined.
q2   a    -    q3    a    // crashing rejects the input.
```

Here, the accept condition is being in state q3 with no more stack.

To do the second option, you'd write a CFG like this:

```
S -> aSbb | aS | e
```

Then your PDA could do the following:

```
push S onto the stack
pop from the stack and push onto the stack one of the productions for S
if you pop a terminal off the stack, consume the nonterminal from input
if you pop a nonterminal off the stack, replace it with some production for that nonterminal
```

This nondeterministically generates every possible derivation according to the CFG. If the input is a string in the language, then one of these derivations will consume all the input and leave the stack empty, which is the halt/accept condition.

Answer (score 0):

We need to construct a pushdown automation for the following language: L = {a^n b^m | 2n>=m }
The given condition is 2n >= m, that means we want the number of a's to be at least half the number of b's. That is, we want at least one a for every two b's. That means if we push all the a's on the stack, we need to read no more than two b's for every a on the stack. This suggests a PDA that works like this:

1. read all the a's, pushing into the stack
2. read b's, popping an a for every two b's you see
3. if you run out of stack but still have b's to process, reject
4. if you run out of input at the same time or sooner than you run out of stack, accept.

The PDA for the problem is as follows −
Transition functions
The transition functions are as follows −

Step 1: δ(q0, a, Z) = (q0, aZ)

Step 2: δ(q0, a, a) = (q0, aa)

Step 3: δ(q0, b, a) = (q1, a)

Step 4: δ(q1, b, a) = (q2, ε)

Step 5: δ(q2, b, a) = (q1, a)

Step 6: δ(q2,b, Z) = dead state.

Step 7: δ(q2,ε, Z) = (qf, Z)